# How to create view in lotusscript having only peple with definied OU

Tags: lotusscript, lotus-formula

Set viewOU = _
s.CurrentDatabase.CreateView("My OU", "SELECT Type="Person" & @Name([OU 1], @UserName) = "LL";");

this not work; howto do it ?

Comment: Where do you want to create this view? What is "CurrentDatabase" in this case?

Comment: it is not important, 
i want to search names.nsf for people with OU =LL

Comment: "i want to search names.nsf for people with OU =LL"
 Would it not make more sense to do an actual search then, instead of creating another view in the database? Who came up with that design?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@UserName returns the *current* user's name. Views select documents. Your expression is not looking at an OU value that is stored in the documents.

If your code is creating a shared view, it selects alll documents if the database is on a server whose OU is "LL" because the server is the "current user" for the indexer so the expression evaluates to @True for every single document. And it selects no documents if the database is on a server whose OU is not "LL" because the expression evaluates to @False for every single document. (But the results will be different if you manually index the view in the Notes client because in that case, the current user is you. It will select all documents if *your* OU is "LL", otherwise it will select no documents.)

What you are *probably* wanting to do is select documents in which a particular field contains a value that is a name, and that name has an OU that matches "LL".  You would do that like this:

```
Set viewOU = _ s.CurrentDatabase.CreateView("My OU", "SELECT Type="Person" & @Name([OU1], @Subset(FullName;1)) = "LL";");
```

The above assumes that you are making this view in a Domino Directory database that uses the standard template, where FullName is the name of the item that contains a list of differently-formatted names for each user, and the first entry in the list is the one that (by convention) contains the user's fully-qualified Domino name.